# How to remove white space gap between body and footer?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, footer

As you can see in the title I have white space between body content and footer on website I am creating right now! I am using wordpress and coding throught editor and I tried to remove padding and margin from site body and footer. I also tried to set it both to relative and move it to one another but as I move them gap just move position. When I set relative position to the footer and add -top to connet it to the body gap is down bellow the page. Please help! Thanky you in advance :D

Here is the CSS code of main page content, and footer:

```css
/* This is inner site (body) content style */

.site-inner {
 background-color: #fff;
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 40px;
}

.minimum-landing .site-inner {
 margin: 40px auto; 
 padding: 60px 60px 20px;
 width: 800px;
}
/* This is footer CSS code */

.site-footer {
 background-color: #231F20;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 padding: 60px 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin:0;
}

.site-footer a,
.site-footer p {
 color: #999;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}

.site-footer a {
 border: none;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.site-footer p {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: The `<article>` tag with class `.entry` has a bottom margin that is pushing the footer down. You may need to restructure your html or remove that margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it it was margin of the body, so I copied CSS path from Opera Inspect element, copied to the CSS editor in wordpress(CLASS) and set margin:0;

Thank you guys on help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your margin in .entry

```
.entry {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```